# Retrieve all mobile devices Google Directory API in .NET Application

Tags: c#, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to Manage Device using Google API in my appilcation.How to retrieve all mobile/chrome OS device ?

CODE :

```
var listReq1 = service.Mobiledevices.List(serviceAccountEmail);
 MobileDevices allUsers = listReq1.Execute();
```

Here,

> serviceAccountEmail = "**Service accounts Key**" (Console.developer.google.com)

I am getting error like

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Bad Request [400]
```

I tried using

```
var listReq= new Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.MobiledevicesResource.ListRequest(service,serviceAccountEmail);
```

Still not working ? I want all details of User just like Below Image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [Mobiledevices: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/list)

> Retrieves a paginated list of all mobile devices for **an** account.

I will see that it takes a customer id as a parmater.

> **customerId**    
>     The unique ID for the customer's Google account. As
>   an account administrator, you can also use the my_customer alias to
>   represent your account's customerId. The customerId is also returned
>   as part of the Users resource.

```
var listReq1 = service.Mobiledevices.List(customerId);
MobileDevices allUsers = listReq1.Execute();
```

You are sending service account email address which I really don't think is your customer id.

Comment: In this case it will return only one record of particular email address.What if i want all records.

Comment: then you run it once for each of your customers.   documentation says it only returns devices for an account not all of  your accounts

Comment: Np just wish I could test it for you.   I am just digging in documentation here :)